# How do I dynamically set the 'mode' attribute of a apex:pageBlock in Salesforce Visualforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have the following in my visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="{!pageBlockMode}">
</apex:pageBlock>
```

And a custom extension with this apex code:

```
public string pageBlockMode 
{ 
    get { return 'edit'; } 
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?  It's simply defaulting to 'detail' mode. Is there a way to dynamically change the 'mode' attribute of a pageBlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my original code works now.  Not sure which version of Visualforce this was fixed/changed in:

Page:

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="{!pageBlockMode}">
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Controller:

```
public string pageBlockMode 
{ 
    get { return 'edit'; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you know that the MODE represents the default user mode for the pageBlock component's child elements. This value determines whether lines are drawn separating field values. Possible values are: 
"detail", in which data is displayed to the user with colored lines; 
"maindetail", in which data is displayed to the user with colored lines and a white background, just like the main detail page for records; and 
"edit", in which data is displayed to the user without field lines. 
If not specified, this value defaults to "detail". These lines have nothing to do with requiredness, they are merely visual separators, that make it easier to scan a detail page.

Comment: Yes.  I am aware of what the "mode" attribute does.  I simply want to be able to change it dynamically and it doesn't appear to work.  It is defaulting to "detail" regardless of what I set in my property.

Answer (score 1):

Based on above comment, why not then try creating two different pageblock sections with RENDERED attribute

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" rendered="{!pageBlockMode=='edit'}">
.....
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock mode="detail" rendered="{!pageBlockMode=='detail'}">
.....
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to avoid 2 pageBlocks.

Comment: Chirag is correct - you'll need two pageBlock sections. As long as you don't have more than one <apex:form> section there won't be a problem - except for having to manage/stare at redundant code that is ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you! It worked for me!

```
public Component.Apex.PageBlock getPageBlockArea(){
     Component.Apex.PageBlock p = new Component.Apex.PageBlock();
     p.title = 'Working';
     p.mode = 'edit';
     return p;
}
```